# Sorting a list with points in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, sorting

In Google Docs, how would I go about sorting a list of chapter numbers (for example) with points in between, e.g. 1.1, 1.21, 1.3 in the right way so that 1.21 follows 1.3?

Answer (score 3):

For want of any better answer so far, I suggest copying your list into a sheet, splitting it on `.` and on  then using the 1,21,3 column to sort the sheet before copying and pasting the revised order back into your document - manually rearrangement may be easier!